# Werkzeug - Template with Twitter Bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, werkzeug

I have the Following Code, am using BootStrap css

```
<ul>
    <li>              
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
    Hello, {{ current_user.name }}
    {% endif %}
    </li>
    <li class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right"><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">LogOut</a>                                                 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the above two tags

in a single line

Answer (score 0):

Add the `pull-right` class to *both*.

Comment: @Rajeev: I think it answers the question. Perhaps you'd like to elaborate as to why you think this is not an answer?

Comment: @Rajeev: Sure, it could be a comment, but I think it is an answer to the question. If it solved their problem and I had posted it as a comment, they could not accept it. As an answer, they can.